# How do i know who has called a pl/sql function inside a procedure when i perform a certain action from fontend(Oracle Apps)?

Tags: sql, oracle, database

I have a pl/sql package: FND_PROFILE.

I perform some actions from the frontend, which should trigger calls to FND_PROFILE.VALUE_SPECIFIC

I need to find who has made these calls.

There were suggestions to use PL/SQL Debugger in JDeveloper. Can somebody please help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [`audit`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_4007.htm)

```
audit execute on FND_PROFILE;
```

To see who ran some function/procedure in the package query `dba_audit_trail`